# Highcharts tooltip refresh not working correctly

Tags: charts, highcharts

I am trying to show the tooltip across multiple charts when the user hovers over any one of the charts.

```
series: {
    point: {
       events: {
          mouseOver: function() {
              syncTooltip(this.series.chart.container, this.x);
          }
       }
    }
}

function syncTooltip(container, p) {

    _.each(totalCharts, (chartType) => {
        let chartContainer = $('#'+chartType);
        let chart = chartContainer.highcharts();
        if (chart && chart.tooltip && container.id != chart.container.id) {
            //I am fetching all points in chart.series whose 'x' value matches with the function parameter 'p'
            var points = process(chart.series);

            if(points.length > 0) {
               chart.tooltip.refresh(points);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

The points array is getting populated correctly. However the charts tooltips are not showing up correctly. Even the highlighted points in the charts are showing up wrong.

[image]

In the above image, I added labels for each data point (x and y coordinates separated by a space).
In the second chart, point three is highlighted whereas point two should be the one highlighted to be in sync with first chart

Comment: add some live example.This will be easier to provide solution

Comment: Your code is not complete and it does not allow to reproduce the issue. Read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try to create a live example, e.g. on jsfiddle.